# What's the status regarding HHVM?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, hhvm, hacklang

I just discovered HHVM, a virtual machine designed to execute PHP (and a closely-related new language called Hack) much more efficiently than the standard PHP interpreter. Read about it at hhvm.com. (I think this started with an effort by Facebook to improve PHP's performance.)

The HHVM developers test its compatibility with popular packages including phpMyAdmin. They claim their latest tests show 99.85% compatibility, whatever that means.

Are the phpMyAdmin developers paying any attention to this effort? Should they?

Comment: phpmyadmin developers shouldn't need to pay attention to the engines used to run PHP, as long as they conform with the language standards defined for the PHP engine - it's up to the engines (Zend, HHVM, etc) to conform, not the developers of applications in PHP

Comment: The status of HHVM is that it's still being developed, independently of the Zend Engine (which is currently the only officially supported PHP parser/executor by the [PHP Group](http://www.php.net/)). The developers of HHVM (mainly Sara Golemon) are actively involved in the development of the PHP language in general as well. It is likely that the HHVM architecture will be further developed and will in the future be a good alternative for the Zend Engine. Right now it does not fully conform to the PHP language standard, but rather to the standard made by Facebook (who fund this effort).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HHVM passes 99.9% of the phpmyadmin tests (on a good day, since they are pretty flakey). We are looking at the last one and will be 100% very soon but I doubt you will run into whatever it is testing since the app works directly on HHVM.

http://hhvm.com/frameworks/